# Отправить переменную в php Ajax'ом

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ситуация такая, есть Ajax запрос к php файлу. Из которого я получаю данные,так же мне нужно  в этот php файл отправить переменную из аттрибута id. Пробовал через подстановку к url `( url: 'http://lab.local/php/info.php' + id_place)` , так же через `data: {'param': id_place}` , не выходит...

```
window.Market.Liner.prototype.next_handler = function(event) {
    var instance = event.data.instance
    var products_place = $(this).parent().parent()
    var liner_place = products_place.find('.liner-line .box.blocks')
    var id_place = liner_place.data('id')
    console.log('id_place: ', id_place)
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'http://lab.local/php/info.php',
      data: {param: id_place},
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log('ОШИБКА')
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('data ', data)
        if (!data) {
          return null
        }
                 var liner_line = products_place.find('.liner-line')
        .append('<div class="box blocks" data-id="'+ next_id +'">' +
                  '<iframe width="294" height="170"'+ 
                    'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ data['data']['video_id'] +'" ' + 
                    'frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""> '+
                  '</iframe>' +
                '</div>')
        var new_position = instance.calc_position(1)
        if (new_position != instance.position) {
          instance.set_position(new_position)
          instance.ui_apply_position()
        }

      }
    })
  }
```

Собственно для чего, чтобы сделать id динам.перем.При нажатии отправляю id, из перебора в php файле берем нужный  и после отправляем data  в js.

```
<?php 
    $string = file_get_contents('./data_php.json');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $array = json_decode($string);
    // var_dump($array);
    $dam =  $_GET['param'];//сюда передаем номер id
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == $dam) {
        echo(json_encode($value, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
        }
    // var_dump(json_encode($value));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Собственно, вопрос решил

Comment: собственно, не хотите поделится ?

Comment: Весь код выше - рабочий.